# Understanding the ground truth poses in the KITTI Dataset

Tags: computer-vision, kitti

Why are there more ground truth poses than point clouds? (i.e. for sequence 00, there are 4541 ground truth poses in the txt file but there are only 4540 point clouds in the velodyne file)